# Changing DateTimePicker format to system format

Tags: c#

Can DateTimePicker's format be changed to whatever format the computer is using? Whether it's mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy? I want the DateTimePicker to change its own format depending on the system format. (C# / Visual Studio)

Comment: it doesnt do that automatically? I am surprised. You sure?

Comment: Mine failed that test when I tried to use the program on 2 different computers unfortunately

Comment: you sure you are not using DateTimeFOrmat.Custom?

Comment: does it have any custom format setting ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.format?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-datetimepicker-format

Comment: set format to say, 'Long' - docs says "The DateTimePicker control displays the date/time value in the long date format set by the user's operating system."

Comment: I didn't change the format to custom. My PC's format is dd/mm/yyyy. It didn't work when I tried to use the same program on a PC that's using mm/dd/yyyy format which is why I'm really confused

Comment: well I just tried it and it works fine. SO you have not done what you say you have done. Write a minimal app and test that (took me 1 minute)

Comment: I did and the same thing happened. I uninstalled visual studio and reinstalled it to see if it'd do anything. That seems to have worked for me.

Comment: Does reinstall VS can solve your problem?

Comment: You are talking about the WinForms DateTimePicker, right? I ask because there are also several 3rd parts controls with this name.

Answer (score 0):

I know its not an answer but here it is working

My pc set to UK date format

[image]

now set to US

[image]

really feels like you have set a custom date format